# Make DIV fill remainder of screen vertically in Responsive FLEX Layout

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

**I'm trying to get something like this going:**

[image]

I found a tutorial that ALMOST does this ->and I made my own `jsfiddle` from it so you can check it out here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gilomer88/x2gfymrk/1/

The problem is that the way the code is written it only works with 3 DIVs: a **HEADER**, a **MAIN**, and a **FOOTER**. (And note that the **FOOTER** is sticky, in a fixed position at the bottom of the screen.)

So the minute I add a third DIV - like the pink-ish one in the image I attached, the **MAIN** DIV ***shrinks*** to let that PINK one also fit in the space that's available between the **HEADER** and the **FOOTER**. And that's not what I want.
What I want is the following:

1. The FOOTER needs to NOT be sticky
2. The MAIN needs to fill the screen, but we should also be able to scroll past it and down to the rest of the page's contents.

Is this just not possible?

Comment: Are you in complete control of what HTML is used?

Comment: Yes, total control.

Answer (score 0):

So I have a suggestion for your problem and that is to nest div elements inside your main element and creating classes for your div elements to fill the space.

```css
.fill-space{
  height: 100vh
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <div class="fill-space"></div>
  <div class="fill-space"></div>
  <div class="fill-space"></div>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

You will have to take whatever information is currently inside your main and put it into its own div element.

Let me know if this helps or if you need further information.